# Issues with Google MLKit Translation From non Latin languages to English

Tags: swift, google-mlkit

Currently trying to build a iOS app using Swift to translate from Chinese to English. I am coming across the issue that when I pass a string like "妳好" to the MLKit Translator, it leads to error `pointer being freed was not allocated`.

Here is my current setup:

- M1 Pro Mac
- XCode 15.2
- GoogleMLKit 4.0.0
- iOS 17 simulator

I saw on the Google documentation that

```
Simulators on M1-based Mac are not supported.

X86_64 simulator is not supported for Translation 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '4.0.0' or later and Smart Reply 'GoogleMLKit/SmartReply', '4.0.0' or later.
```

Does this mean that this kit version won't work with my setup? Any tips on how to resolve this issue on not being able to translate from non Latin languages to English?

I have tried English to Chinese and that works and sometimes Chinese to English works as well, but more often than not, the error `pointer being freed was not allocated` appears and crashed the application.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not at all clear, but I was in the same situation and discovered the following:

1. you can not run MLKit including Translate on an Apple Silicon CPU
   That includes both running to a MacOS target or to an iOS Sim target on a MacOS Xcode system.
2. you CAN compile / link / load / run from Apple Silicon Xcode to an actual physical iPhone/ipad.

Here is the PodFile I used:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# Modified from Google MLKit Translate Example

platform :ios, '17.0'

target 'Utility 1' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AES Sentence Utility 1

    pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '4.0.0'

end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '16.0'
         end
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I assmed it was something to do with the MacOS Xcode. Glad I got a second confirmation!